# Understanding my crash log for iPhone App

Tags: ios, memory, crash, report, memory-leaks

I'm having trouble understanding my crash log.  I can understand that it crashes on the 9th thread.  So looking at the 9th thread I have

```
Thread 9 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x30da4f78 objc_msgSend + 16
1   APLfree                         0x0009be1c 0x1000 + 634396
2   Foundation                      0x30514a7a -[NSThread main]
3   Foundation                      0x305a858a __NSThread__main__
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3763872e _pthread_start
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x376385e8 thread_start
```

Does this mean that libsystem_c.dylib caused the crash or could it be libobjc.A.dylib?

I don't get the crash myself but I obtained this from the crash logs from real users of my app.  It occurs in iOS 5.1, 5.0, 4.3 and 4.2.6 at least.  So it's not a new bug in the latest iOS.

I suspect it might be a problem with releasing memory but I'm not very good at tracking those problems down so if there's any advice on how to fix memory leaks, etc that would also help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Travis

Comment: Generally you read stack traces from the top down.  That means that libsystem_c.dylib caused the crash, but not really, you caused the crash, probably by passing an invalid pointer or freeing it when you shouldn't have.  I'm not a pro at reading iOS code, but I'd wager to say that this stack report isn't really telling you much.  Maybe you should look into using a dynamic instrumentation tool to track down leaks (looks like valgrind works with the iOS simulator..)

Comment: I agree with @KristopherMicinski. The another way could be to insert breakpoints & finding the place that causes crash

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the crash on your own device by any chance? If so, you could do it with the debugger running and see exactly which line of code caused the problem, or what object was being freed at the time. You might also try running with `NSZombies` enabled to see if you're double-freeing something, or freeing something which was not allocated.

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice guys.  The problem is I don't get the crash myself.  Perhaps it's an intermittent problem or maybe only older devices get the crash and mine doesn't.  It's hard to say.  If I could reproduce it easily myself I could find it.

Comment: It is very very unlikely to be related to an older device. Usually such problems occur either for a specific sequence the app is used, or occurs after a long usage time. In either case, use [UIAutomation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009771-CH1-SW1) or [KIF](https://github.com/square/KIF) to create user interaction test cases that run your app in different sequences and for a longer time. This will most likely reveal the bug in a reproducible way.

Comment: Also since the crash doesn't happen on the main thread, but in some background processing, it IS very likely that you are releasing an object that you are also using on another thread. If you symbolicate the report line 1 would reveal the class and method where the crash happens and that could also be a great hint on where to look for such a memory problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try set a Zombie objects enabling and recreate a bug:

1) Press cmd + Shift + ,

2) Choose "Run" at left panel -> "Diagnostics" at right panel

3) Set checkbox at "Enable Zombie Objects"

And try recreate a bug, and your Xcode will show, where is error.